# C# : Resolve IP into host name when a host has more than 1 ip

Tags: c#, networking, dns, pcap.net

This is my first ever question on StackOverflow. So, if there are any mistakes, please ignore them. If you're facing problem to understand my question, please let me know, I'll try me best to explain my problem :) .

Currently I'm trying to create a packet sniffer using **pcap.net in c#**. I'm facing a problem while resolving the ip addresses into hostnames.

**Here is my problem :** 
When a website has more than 1 ip address, for example when I type the command in command prompt

```
nslookup yahoo.com
```

I got the following output

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.0.1: Timed out
Server: google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address: 8.8.8.8

Non-authorative answer:
Name: yahoo.com
Addresses: 206.190.36.45, 98.139.183.24, 98.138.253.109
```

So, it is clear that I have more than 1 ip address for yahoo.com.

Now, I'm using the following piece of code, which is working fine for the hosts having 1 ip address( *eg. when I've ip source / destination as 8.8.8.8 it is giving me the result google-public-dns-a.google.com*)

```
private void PacketHandler(Packet packet)
{
        IpV4Datagram ip = packet.Ethernet.IpV4; 

        string sourceHost = ip.Source.ToString();
        string destinationHost = ip.Destination.ToString();

        #region Code to get the host name of the source ip and the destination ip

        string tempSourceIP = sourceHost;
        string tempDestinationIP = destinationHost;
        IPHostEntry source_ipHostEntry, destination_ipHostEntry;
        try
        {
            source_ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(sourceHost);
            destination_ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(destinationHost);
            sourceHost = tempSourceIP + "   ::   (" + source_ipHostEntry.HostName + ")";
            destinationHost = tempDestinationIP + "   ::   (" + destination_ipHostEntry.HostName + ")";

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sourceHost = tempSourceIP;
            destinationHost = tempDestinationIP;
        }
        #endregion
}
```

I'm adding the results sourceHost and destinationHost to GUI (that's a datagrid to be precise) for displaying results.

My question is - Is there a way to find out whether the source IP or the destination IP belongs to the list of IPs of a host which is unknown( **eg. if my source IP or destination IP is 206.190.36.45, how can I find out that the IP belongs to yahoo.com**)?

**UPDATE** : I was surfing the internet to find a solution to my question and I found this link [How to retrieve a list of websites from an IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968248/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-websites-from-an-ip-address) . This partially solves my problem, because there are still some ip addresses which cannot be resolved to their host names even after following this method. And since I'm making a packet sniffer, this method might not be the best one. Because I want to show the user, the host name of the ip address in real time, when the values are being loaded in the GUI( I mean my datagrid). And I would be glad to know - if the solution provided in the link, is the only way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try rDNS.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup

But as mentioned there:

> not all IP addresses have a reverse entry.

Comment: Your link is very helpful. Thanks. "not all IP addresses have a reverse entry" - Actually, that's the reason why my code has restrictions. The same is true for nslookup as well. But I've a question - how do the websites like domaintools resolve ips? If they uses some sort of file, where can I get that file? Actually that's the reason why I started thinking and came up with this question.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer, but it's not working because of my reputation. Please don't mind.

Comment: I guess this sites keep some sort of reverse tables. Note that they also have limitations:
"
Limitations of the Reverse IP Lookup tool:

Results include all .com, .net, .org, .biz, .us and .info domains plus any other gTLD or ccTLD domain listed on the IP we know about.
Domains added to an IP address are updated daily.
Domains removed from any specific IP address may not be reflected for up to two weeks.
"

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me.